# Error while installing ShengBTE

Tags: python, software-assistance, phonons, thermal, shengbte

I am trying to install the thirdorder script that is mean to work in tandem with [ShengBTE](https://www.shengbte.org/) on an Ubuntu OS, but I'm getting the following error:

```
npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   17 | #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      |  ^~~~~~~
thirdorder_core.c:559:10: fatal error: spglib/spglib.h: No such file or directory
  559 | #include "spglib/spglib.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please direct me how to solve this.

Comment: What are you doing to try to install this package? From the README: "Compiling can be as easy as running `bash ./compile.sh`. However, if you have installed spglib to a nonstandard directory, you will have to perform some simple editing on setup.py so that the compiler can find it. Please refer to the comments in that file." This looks to be the issue you are having, so you would need to install spglib and let the program know where it is by editing setup.py.

Comment: @Tyberius i am trying to learn how to compile lattice thermal conductivity in QE. Since i am a beginner to all this, and have just installed Ubuntu, I am facing all these issues. It isn't solved yet, but i am trying.

Comment: Yeah a lot of these scientific packages can be a real pain to install. Try messing with spglib installation and you can update your question with any additional issues you run into.

Comment: Which versions of thirdorder, Python and numpy are you using?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you haven't installed the libsymspg-dev package.

Comment: @epsilon02fft according to Phil you have to first install the libsymspg-dev package? Have you tried that yet?

Comment: The question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments or if another user wants to provide an answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani I am still working on it. The spglib required here is of atztogo who developed phonopy. I am trying to solve how to run ShengBTE.

Comment: @Tyberius Sir I was not able to login before, but now I will try to update to my ques as & when I can solve them myself.

Comment: @epsilon02fft Did you have any luck with this in the last 2 months?

Comment: @NikeDattani No Sir. I think I need to start installing it again. I have not been able to do calculations using ShengBTE.

Comment: How did this go? Have you found an answer now? It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue since it's been there for more than 12 months now! Please update us! Did you try to install it again?

Comment: @NikeDattani No, I did succeed in it. Someone who has done these particular calculations can only help. I did not find anyone who could help. You may remove it from queue if you wish so.

Comment: @epsilon02fft do you mean that you did ***not*** succeed in it?

Comment: @NikeDattani No, Sir. I did not. I have currently enrolled in my Ph.D. and I am hoping If I get a new system, I will try it again. But, it will take some time and I don't want to create any problems in the working of the Matter modelling community. If someday I do it again I will post it properly here.

Comment: @NikeDattani Please close this question too. As the answer below seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The thirdorder program uses the symmetry library "spglib", and needs its header files (files ending `.h`). The error you're seeing is telling you that the compiler can't find these header files, probably because they haven't been installed on your machine.

The files aren't usually installed if you just select the spglib library in your package manager, you will usually have to install the spglib *developer* package; on Ubuntu, the relevant package is `libsymspg-dev`. While you're installing it, it's worth getting the Python bindings as well, which is `python3-spglib`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation.